# Upgrade postgresql 9.4 to 9.6 on debian stretch (9.0)

Tags: postgresql, debian-stretch

I want to upgrade my PostgreSQL 9.4 cluster to PostgreSQL 9.6 since upgrading debian to 9.0 (stretch) I lost PostgreSQL 9.4 however and it's also not in the repos anymore.

Without PostgreSQL 9.4 I however can't upgrade using pg_upgradecluster

Shall I install PostgreSQL 9.4 using an installer? Will it work on Debian stretch? 
Can I copy my cluster to a machine with Debian 8 and both versions of PostgreSQL to upgrade on?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upgrade the cluster after installing PostgreSQL 9.4 from the PostgreSQL apt repository as described on https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian
PostgreSQL 9.4 works on Debian 9, at least for upgrading a cluster.